# Can you ruin a battery by letting it fully drain?

Tags: battery

I have an LG Quantum C900 Windows 7.5 phone. I accidentally didn't have the charging cord plugged in when I thought it was, so instead of charging it fully drained. Now when I try and charge it all I get is a picture of a battery that has a red stripe at the bottom. I read elsewhere that you can get over this by removing the battery for a while. I did that and still have the battery icon on the screen. I've had other phones that I didn't use for months and they recharged. Is this an issue though - let the battery go dead and it can go bad?

Comment: Have you tried to plug the charger and leave the phone alone by some minutes? I had a similar problem. The phone refuse to turn on even with charger plugged. So I plugged it and leave some minutes and it turn of still with battery at 0%. Now it is ok.

Comment: @VitorCanova Yes, I had plugged it in for many hours. I did see what you saw at one point - 0% battery and phone turned on (while plugged in). But then it went back to the battery display for hours again. But finally I went to turn it off and on and the system came up and then it did fully charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LG Quantum C900 uses a lithium ion battery. If you run it completely dead it can be [irreversibly ruined](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/lithium-ion-battery.htm). However, the electronic circuitry is designed to make it more difficult to drain. It is designed to "shut off" the phone when the battery is around 2-3% charge remaining. The battery will still naturally discharge and it is possible for it to completely drain.

My suggestion would be to plug it in and wait up to several days. My boss had an LG Windows Phone he let sit for several months and it took about two days of charging for the phone to wake up again.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it finally did charge up, and the applicable duration was "days" instead of the normal hours.

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to save your phone! It seems odd that it should take so long to "charge" your phone. But once it is in a super low state, I've seen multiple phones take several days to become usable again.